# Como gerar Dígito Verificador da Chave de NFe/NFC-e/CF-e/CT-e

Tags: sql-server

Como calcular o Dígito Verificador da Chave NFe?

Por exemplo, qual o dígito verificador da Chave com 43 posições:

'2411050954052500019455001000000709124205076'

Comment: Você está com dúvida em como é o cálculo, ou a dúvida está em como aplicar o cálculo no `SQL Server`?

Comment: Como aplicar o cálculo, mas com o auxilio de [Calculo de dígito verificador - SQL Server - Fórum iMasters](https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/446046-resolvido%C2%A0calculo-de-d%C3%ADgito-verificador/) foi possível identificar uma maneira, vou incluir como resposta aqui!

Answer (score 0):

Segue um código  de uma função que auxilia:

```
CREATE FUNCTION F_CHAVE_DFe_GERAR_ChaveSemDV(@ChaveSemDV nvarchar(43)) RETURNS nvarchar(44)
BEGIN

DECLARE 
    @Dv Nvarchar(1)

--- PEGO O TAMANHO DO NÚMERO DE ENTRADA
DECLARE @TamanhoDoCodigoSemDV INTEGER
SET @TamanhoDoCodigoSemDV  = LEN(@ChaveSemDV)

-- CRIO UMA VARIÁVEL SOMATÓRIO 
DECLARE @Soma INTEGER
SET @Soma = 0

--CRIO UM MULTIPLICADOR
DECLARE @Multiplicador INTEGER
SET @Multiplicador = 2

--CRIO UMA VARIÁVEL PARA FAZER O CALULO ATÉ O TAMANHO DO NUMERO DE ENTRADA 
DECLARE @i integer
SET @i = 1

WHILE @i <= @TamanhoDoCodigoSemDV 
  BEGIN
    --PRINT convert(varchar(3),@Multiplicador) + ' - ' + convert(varchar(3), @i) + ' - ' + (LEFT(RIGHT(@ChaveSemDV, @i),1))
    SET @Soma = @Soma + (LEFT(RIGHT(@ChaveSemDV, @i),1) * @Multiplicador)
    SELECT @Multiplicador = 
        CASE -- Reinicia o Multiplicador em 2 quando maior que 9
            WHEN @Multiplicador < 9 
            THEN @Multiplicador + 1 
            ELSE 2 END 
    SET @i = @i + 1
  END

--PRINT 'Soma: ' + CONVERT(varchar, @Soma)

SELECT @Dv = CASE WHEN @Soma%11 IN (0, 1) THEN 0 ELSE 11 - (@Soma%11) END

RETURN @ChaveSemDV + @Dv

END
```

Chamada:

```
SELECT F_CHAVE_DFe_GERAR_ChaveSemDV('2411050954052500019455001000000709124205076');
```

O resultado é:

```
24110509540525000194550010000007091242050760
```